# Finding ID in worksheet and return row in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

For context, I'm building a database of users and their hobbies. Users input their data via UserForm1 by entering their name, then ticking a large number of checkboxes representing different hobbies. When submitted, this saves to a worksheet, with each user as a row (name as a string, the checkboxes as true/false values) and the user is given an ID number.

In UserForm2, users enter their ID number to return their record, so they can update their own data. I want to add a macro that searches for their record by ID number, and *returns UserForm1* with checkboxes ticked/unticked corresponding to the yes/no values (like the first macro in reverse). The user should then be able to tick/untick boxes to update their record, and save over their old data.

This is the code for UserForm1 (users input their data to the worksheet):

```
Private Sub saveAndCloseCommandButton_Click()

'When user clicks Save & Quit, save record as row
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
        lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            With ws
                .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = nameTextBox.Value
                .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = deptTextBox.Value
                .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = notesTextBox.Value

'.Cells(1Row, 4) contains ID so do not write data to this column
'Give ID number to the user via MsgBox.

                MsgBox "Saved. Your Skills Database ID is " & .Cells(lRow, 4) & ". Remember this!", VBA.VbMsgBoxStyle.vbOKOnly     

     'Populate the spreadsheet based on which skills the user selected, as TRUE (checkbox ticked) or FALSE (unticked).

                .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Value
                .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = CheckBox2.Value
                ...and so on, until
                .Cells(lRow, 151).Value = CheckBox148.Value

            End With
        Call resetForm

        'Close the form after saving
        Unload Me

     End If
End If

End Sub

'This is all the stuff that happens when the form resets (called above).
'The checkboxes should auto-untick.

Private Sub resetForm()

'Set all text boxes to blank
nameTextBox.Value = ""
deptTextBox.Value = ""
notesTextBox.Value = ""

'Set Focus on the Name text box
UserForm1.nameTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: How is the data saved to the worksheets? You store headers as hobbies and then True False on each column depending on the checkbox?

Comment: To my mind there is many about supplying easy changes in future, there should be: 1) Own Type 2) Procedure that copies data from form to OwnType 3) procedure that copies data from OwnType to Form 4) procedure for writing OwnType to Excel sheet (adds new, or rewrites old) 5) procedure that reads OwnType from Excel sheet from definite row

Comment: Damian - exactly. Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/3YZFf95
Users input their data with Userform1: https://ibb.co/VCCSb7W
Userform2 is simply an input box for ID: https://ibb.co/vxGLjM3
When the user inputs their ID, I want it to return UserForm1 (or an identical copy) with the boxes ticked/untciked depending on the TRUE/FALSE data in their row.